# how to rewrite code from DAO to ADO?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado, dao

We got some old legacy application which was developed during 2000 and  we have moved from access 2003 to 2007. When I am trying to run a module of an application, it is giving me an error:

> "Run-time error 3847. ODBCDirect is no longer supported. Rewrite the code to use ADO instead of DAO".

And it highlights to the line `Set WS = CreateWorkspace("NewWS", "", "", dbUseODBC)`. As I am really new to Access, I did research before posting this issue here but no luck. I am trying to rewrite the code to use ADO instead of DAO.

Following is my old vba code:

```
Public Function GetID (ByRef SegmentItem As clsSegmentDefinitions) As Long 
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Dim qdfNewID As QueryDef
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim rsNewID As Recordset
    Dim NaturalDescription As String
    Dim WS As Workspace
    Dim con As Connection 
    Set WS = CreateWorkspace("NewWS", "", "", dbUseODBC)
    WS.DefaultCursorDriver = dbUseODBCCursor
    Set con = WS.OpenConnection("", , , SQLConnectString)
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    DoCmd.OpenForm " frmQuickAdd_AddNatural ", , , , , acDialog, SegmentItem.AddValue
    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    If Form_frmQuickAdd_AddNatural.Tag Then
        Set qdf = con.CreateQueryDef("", "{ ? = call sp_Insert(?, ?, ?) }")
        qdf.Parameters.Refresh
        qdf![@prmDescription] = Left(Form_frmQuickAdd_AddNatural.txtSegmentDescription, 34)
        qdf![@prmCreateUser] = CurrentUser
        qdf![@prmProjectID] = 0
        qdf.Execute
        Set qdfNewID = CodeDb.CreateQueryDef("")
        qdfNewID.Connect = SQLConnectString
        qdfNewID.ReturnsRecords = True
        qdfNewID.SQL = "sp_GetNewSegmentID"
        Set rsNewID = qdfNewID.OpenRecordset
        If Not IsNull(rsNewID!MaxOfSegmentID) Then
            GetID = rsNewID!MaxOfSegmentID
        Else
            GetID = 0
        End If        
    Else
        GetID = 0
    End If
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmQuickAdd_AddNatural"    
End Function
```

I had started to rewrite code but I have no clue if it is suppose to be like this at all.

```
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

cnn.Open "Provider=mssql;Data Source=" & dbq & ";User Id=" & uid & ";Password=" & pwd
With rst
    .Open "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " & tbl, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    num = .Fields(0)
    .Close
End With
cnn.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
```

Comment: It will be a lot of work to rewrite to ADO. Alternatively, modify - still using DAO - to work without the ODBC WorkSpace.

Comment: I'd port the whole thing to SQL Server free edition.   I spent time with Access recently still loads of bugs.  Dreadful.

Comment: I've reformatted your question to fix the code blocks, but your question is essentially *too broad* at this point. You can find information about ADO in [Documentation.SO](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3578/working-with-ado#t=201612301821243706514); once you're stuck on a *specific* problem, you'll have a *specific* question and we'll be able to give you *specific* answers. Right now it looks like you're asking other people to do the "translation" work for you, which isn't what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: @Mat'sMug: I will be studying that documentation. Thank you

Comment: @S Meaden: --  The user is already using SQL server, and suggesting SQL server would not allow one to create forms and the UI which clearly are involved in the given sample code. So moving to SQL would not solve the UI issue unless you suggest another client development tool. Access makes a great client to Oracle or in this case SQL server. As noted the user is already using SQL server and store proc names are clearly visible in the given sample code. So the database engine in question is ALREADY SQL server. So how does porting to SQL server allow one to build forms and a UI?

Answer (score 1):

First, you really don’t want to introduce ADO into an application built and designed around DAO. Worse, is ADO has been on its way out for about 15 years now. In fact SQL server is dropping support for oleDB which ADO works on. (so don’t go there).

See this link about SQL server dropping oleDB support:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlnativeclient/archive/2011/08/29/microsoft-is-aligning-with-odbc-for-native-relational-data-access.aspx

The industry has moved away from ADO and all major vendors are suggesting to use Open Database Connectivity as the industry standard. (that means ODBC).

I would create and save a pass-though query in Access. You code can then be re-written as:

```
Public Function GetID(ByRef SegmentItem As String) As Long

  Dim strSQL     As String

  strSQL = "sp_Insert('" & _
           Left(Form_frmQuickAdd_AddNatural.txtSegmentDescription, 34) & "'," & _
           "'" & CurrentUser & "', 0)"

  With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPass")
     .SQL = strSQL
     .ReturnsRecords = False
     .Execute
  End If

  With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPass")
     .SQL = "sp_GetNewSegmentID"
     .ReturnsRecords = True
     GetID = Nz(.OpenRecordset()("MaxOfSegmentID"),0)
  End With

End Function
```

So create one pass-though query. And you can use it quite much in all places where you were using JET-DIRECT. In access 2007, jet-direct support was dropped, but use of a simple pass-though query will more than suffice and also as the above shows save buckets of coding and developer time. If the “left” expression you have can return a null, then you likely need to wrap that expression in a nz() to return a “” (null string) or the appropriate value.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am studying about the pass-through query online. So, "qrypass" above is the pass-through query, right? What goes inside pass-through query? Is it the store procedure sp_insert?

Comment: You can place anything you want inside of the pass-though query. So just test the PT with a simple select count(*) from tblCustomers. PT query can start out with any legal t-sql statement. Above shows you will "often" modify the .SQL text property of that PT query to whatever on the fly. So first test the PT query by clicking on it to run it Once working  then above code changes the .SQL property as per above on the fly. This in allows you to stuff + use ANY t-sql in that PT query. It also means you don't mess with connection strings in code and works well to replace jet-direct code.

Comment: any yes in above qryPass is the name I used for the PT query - it can be any name you want. This approach is preferred since the rest of your DAO recordset code does not have to be re-written and will work as before. So this approach results in the least amount of changes to existing DAO recordset code.

Comment: Update: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2017/10/06/announcing-the-new-release-of-ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/

Comment: Note that the code seems to create a separate ODBCDirect connection independent of Access, meaning that ADO would really do make sense here (or at least it used to).

Comment: -1 Op Asked How not Should. Granted this isn't a very well formed question as this is likely the answer the Op needed but this answer should have been a Discussion point since its definitely not an answer to the question as stated. And years later someone else might actually need the real Answer and stumble on this question.

Comment: Well, ODBC direct is depreciated. So, the question then becomes SHOULD one follow the error message and follow that advice? And my answer is in 99% of cases - no you should not introduce ADO - it is a bad idea, and furthermore in the vast majority of cases not only a bad idea, but not required. The better solution is to use a PT query. it also less code and work to boot. I suppose someone can ask how to drive off a cliff, and you argue that any advice not giving a answer is wrong, but it also bad advice, and a bad idea. Surely one is not suggesting it better to give  bad advice to answer then?